# Show that the group of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is equal to the product of it's subgroups...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, group-isomorphism

Show that the group of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ $$\sigma_4$$ is equal to the product of it's subgroups 
$$C_2\times C_2 $$ and$$D_6=(x^3=y^2=1, yx=x^2y)$$

I'm not sure whether to just multiply the groups and find all $24$ terms or whether there is a short cut using the semi-direct product I know $$Aut(C_2\times C_2)\cong D_6 $$

Comment: See Example 3 [here](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/semidirect.pdf).

Comment: You haven't specified how $K_4$ or $D_6$ are subgroups of $S_4$. By theory we know that there is only one possibility for $D_6$, but it'd be nice if it was explicitly said how $D_6$ is being viewed as a subgroup. And there are multiple possible copies of $K_4$ in $S_4$.